# How can I make a div, which is bigger (in height) then the window, be fixed but still scroll able without any sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, fixed

The best example I could find on the web was on this Yahoo page. The div on the right is fixed. However, whenever I scroll up it scrolls with the page all the way to the top and when I scroll down, it scrolls to the bottom of the div.

https://www.yahoo.com/news/

[image]

Until now, I managed to create this code:

```css
.sidediv{
  height: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
max-height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
  
  }
#content{
  height: 2000px;
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  }
#left{
  height:1000px;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  }
#right{
  width: 120px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="left">
    Left side, main content
    </div>
  <div id="right">
      <div class="sidediv">
        Side content here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that that Yahoo! page uses JavaScript for the effect, but (if I understood your request correctly) this can be achieved with CSS only.

There's a fairly recent new value to the `position` CSS property, which is [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning). Allow me to give you an example of it in action (simulating what I believe to be your request):

```css
aside {
    position: sticky;  /* Oh yeah! Sticky! */
    top: 0;  /* Distance from top when it's stuck. Play around with this value a bit */

    background-color: #B8c1c8;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {  margin: 0;  }

header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

article {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER! Awesome! </header>
<nav>NAVIGATION BAR! Awesome!</nav>
<div>
    <aside>STICKY SIDE! Awesome!</aside>
    <article>
      <h2> Scroll the page down </h2>
      <p> to see the effect </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2> Title! </h2>
      <p> Potatoes! </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2> Title! </h2>
      <p> Potatoes! </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2> Title! </h2>
      <p> Potatoes! </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2> Title! </h2>
      <p> Potatoes! </p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Basically, this makes it so an element stays on the page when you scroll down, but only *if* you scroll down. It behaves normally if you don't.

However, the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) for it doesn't look too great. Internet Explorer, Edge, Chrome 55- and most of the mobile browsers don't support it at all, which is a shame. Hopefully in a few years it'll be standard.

And hopefully this is still relevant to you! Cheers!